# Woocommerce on Subdirectory

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i'm owner of a famous shopping online site in Italy, [www.outletscarpeonline.it](https://www.outletscarpeonline.it)

If you look at my site, it is based on woocommerce, what i need now is to create a new section of site for man styles, like www.outletscarpeonline.it/uomo/

in this section i will add all man styles.
Is it possibile to do with only one dashboard of woocommerce?
My necessity is to have woman and men style in one site.

Thanks in advance to all!

Comment: I guess you need this section like this `https://www.outletscarpeonline.it/offerte/`, If it is the case, Yes this is possible.

Comment: no. I need a section like https://www.outletscarpeonline.it/uomo/ that contains all product for men separately from woman...is it possible? And how?

Comment: This is possible. You just have to render only men related products on this hyperlink.  You can separate products by assigning `men` category.

Comment: no...in this case will not work! i need a new home page for man and all for man...best that i can do is to enable a multisite